# Mint 18.1, Ckan, SOLR schema version not supported

Tags: solr, ckan, linux-mint

I'm a front-end developer and I need to do a Ckan Theme. To do so, I need a working source install of CKAN on my system. I'm using Mint 18.1 and installing Ckan 2.6.2.

Following the steps of the installation of ckan's [docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) I've got a warning and an error at step 6 as shown on the image.

[image: error printscreen]

As you can see the last line says `SOLR schema version not supported: 2.7. Supported versions are [2.3]` and I can't proceed with the installation. Searching on the Internet I found people having the same problem, but using Docker (have no idea what is this) and their solutions didn't work for me.

**Because I have a really short time to build this theme I gave up CKAN 2.6.2 and installd 2.5.2 and everything worked fine.**

Answer (score 0):

The SOLR schema that comes with CKAN 2.6.2 is version 2.3, so somehow you have got 2.7, which is provided with later versions of CKAN. Maybe you installed CKAN master and the schema is lingering from then.

Here are some steps so that you can find out where the problem is:

You can check the version of the schema in the CKAN source repo on your disk:

```
grep 'name="ckan" version=' /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/solr/schema.xml
```

You would have then installed this file into Solr (in Step 5, using the 'ln' command). You can check the version in Solr:

```
grep 'name="ckan" version=' /etc/solr/conf/schema.xml
```

(When this file is changed, you need to restart SOLR (i.e. jetty) for it to take effect - see the docs again).

You can see what schema SOLR is actually using:

```
curl -s 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/file/?contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=schema.xml'|grep 'name="ckan" version='
```

Please do feed back on these.

Comment: Hi @d-read, I feel really sorry, but I can't give you feed back on this, I have a really short time to develop this theme, so I gave up CKAN 2.6.2 and installed CKAN 2.5.2 and everything did work fine.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your Docker container for SOLR is a newer version than that is not compatible with CKAN 2.6.2.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I'm not using Docker. It isn't a requirement for ckan installation.